# How can i solve the problem when closing git console that says "Processes are running in session"

Tags: git, process, mintty

I am currently working with the git commands. When I direct into my folder, where the git repository is at everything works. When i then say "git log" it prints all my commits. But then i cant type again any command. It just says: "no next tag (press RETURN)". When i then try to close git it pops up a window with the name "mintty". It says: "Processes are running in session..." How can i solve this problem that i can type in another git command or close git properly?

I can say "ok" and then my git closes, but this cannot be the solution for this problem.

I expect to write some new commands into the console and i expect to close git without this error message, that processes are still running.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `git log` starts an interactive session that allows you to scroll through the output. For example, you can press space to move to the next page and use up and down arrows to navigate through the logs. **To exit this, press `q`.** This will return you to the command line prompt. Then you can type another command or quit the Git Bash or CMD session by closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your OS and your Window shell (even on Windows, it could be POwershell, CMder or CMD `git bash`)

But just in case it is a [terminal pager issue (`LESS`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)), try:

```
export LESS=-JMQRiFX
```

Then try git log, and see if the issue persists